# iPhone - Change the text on a UISwitch from "ON/OFF" to "TRUE/FALSE"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiswitch

What would be the best way to go about doing this? Is there a simple solution? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UISwitch Action method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995813/uiswitch-action-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't customize this control for submission as per apple Norms

But try this Link

http://www.catamount.com/blog/1063/uicustomswitch-customizing-uiswitch-color-it-change-labels/

instead try with UISegmentControl for displaying - TRUE / FALSE

Answer (score 2):

You can however use SSSwitch from SSToolkit : https://github.com/samsoffes/sstoolkit

With this replacement switch, you can customize the labels to read what you want.